# Future of WSE3.0 webservice/ASMX project and C# desktop client consuming ASMX proxy webservice

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-2022, asmx, web-reference, wse3.0

We have a client and web project running fine in Visual Studio 2013. The web project has ASMX files. VS has a plugin WSE3.0 installed for building ASMX files fine. The Client (desktop C# project), then consumes the methods exposed from ASMX files by adding 'Web Reference' to the Client project.

Now we are trying to build these projects in Visual Studio 2022. No issues building the web project with ASMX files, happy with that.

On the Client Desktop C# project, we are trying to consume the "RevenueServiceWse" from proxy using WebServicesClientProtocol. It used to be like below in Visual Studio 2013.

public partial class RevenueServiceWse : Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol {

But now the proxy is getting produced only with below which is SoapHttpClientProtocol in Visual Studio 2022.

public partial class RevenueService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {

I know this is because WSE is obsolete and hence Visual Studio 2022 is unable to produce proxy with WwbServicesClientProtocol.

But, what is the future of our Client desktop (C#) and Webservice project?
What are the next steps?
I tried to add WSE3.0 plugin but Visual Studio 2022 doesn't like it like 2013.
Both Client and webservice are huge banking project and we are external supporting it.

I tried to consume SoapHttpClientProtocol instead of WebServicesClientProtocol as WebServicesClientProtocol  is not produced anymore in 2022 Visual studio. However, I am having several problems like 'action header', 'Security header' issues. I tried to resolve these for quite good time now but unable to resolve.

Could someone guide what's the future of these projects (C# windows forms project consuming Webservices using ASMX)? Note that both client and server projects are in our control. How to get these working in Visual Studio 2022? (Don't want to produce proxy in lower Visual Studio 2013 version and copy over to 2022). Looking for next steps please.